# Showing local storage values on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a survey that stores values to **local storage**. Trying to make a very simple 'admin' page that its sole purpose is to only **display the local storage** in an semi organized fashion via table etc. I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.

Here is what i have to store it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#Save').click(function (e) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit? You will not be able to go back.')) {
            var person = $("#FirstName").val() + "." + $('#LastName').val();
            $('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
                var value = $(this).val(),
                    name = $(this).attr('name');
                localStorage[person + "." + name] = value;
                window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
                console.log('stored key: ' + name + ' stored value: ' + value);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

the key stored is firstname.lastname.element,value. if it could simply display basically like the console view ordered by key that would be great. Any point in a direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered jStorage ? http://www.jstorage.info/

Comment: I'm not familiar but i'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you really can't manipulate your server side code, I highly recommend that you use `$.ajax` to post your form to the server and then serve back a response. I doubt that local storage was intended for form submission in quite this way. Otherwise, see below.

In order for you to show your localStorage items on the next page, you need to reference your localStorage items on the next page. After you change `window.location.href`, the previous page's context is no longer valid, thus `name` and `value` no longer exist. You should use something similar to this for both pages:
**Submit.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Save').click(function (e) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit? You will not be able to go back.')) {
            var person = $("#FirstName").val() + "." + $('#LastName').val();
            $('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
                var value = $(this).val(),
                    name = $(this).attr('name');
                localStorage["name"] = name;
                localStorage["person"] = person;
                localStorage[person + "." + name] = value;
                window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
                console.log('stored key: ' + name + ' stored value: ' + value);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Confirmation.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    var name = localStorage["name"];
    var person = localStorage["person"];
    var value = localStorage[person + "." + name];
    console.log('stored key: ' + name + ' stored value: ' + value);
});
```